# Algoritmo em Portugol

Tags: portugol, portugol-studio

estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade e a premissa é:

Desenvolva um algoritmo que:

a) faça a leitura de 60 idades;

b) agrupe as idades em três vetores conforme a faixa etária abaixo.

Lembrando que existem cenários possíveis em que o usuário pode informar apenas 60 idades da faixa menores, por exemplo.

```
Faixa    Intervalo
Menores    0-18 anos
Adultos    19-60 anos
Idosos    Maiores de 60 anos
```

c) imprimir todas as idades separadas por faixa, como por exemplo:

```
Menores: 2, 4, 5, 13, 18.
Adultos: 20, 20, 45, 55, 60. 
Idosos: 67, 68, 72, 78, 79, 80.
```

d) imprimir a quantidade de pessoas por faixa, como por exemplo:

```
Menores: 5.
Adultos: 5. 
Idosos: 6.
```

e) imprimir a média de idade por faixa, como por exemplo:

```
Menores: 8,4.
Adultos: 40. 
Idosos: 74.
```

f) imprimir a média geral, como por exemplo:

```
Média geral: 42,875.
```

Meu codigo ficou assim:

```
var
    idade: vetor[1..60] de inteiro
    menor: vetor[1..60] de inteiro
    adulto: vetor[1..60] de inteiro
    idoso: vetor[1..60] de inteiro
    i: inteiro
    ci, cm, ca, cid: inteiro
    si, sm, sa, sid: inteiro
    mi, mm, ma, mid: real
inicio
    // Seção de Comando
    Escreval (" As idades são : ")

   para i de 1 ate 60 faca
        leia(idade[i])
        ci := ci + 1
        si := si + idade[i]
        mi <- si / ci

        se (idade[i] >= 0) e (idade[i] <= 18) entao
            menor[i] <- idade[i]
            cm := cm + 1    // contador
            sm := sm + idade[i]     // soma das idades
            mm <- sm / cm       // média das idades
        fimse

        se (idade[i] >= 19) e (idade[i] <=60) entao
            adulto[i] <- idade[i]
            ca := ca + 1
            sa := sa + idade[i]
            ma <- sa / ca
        fimse

        se idade[i] > 61 entao
            idoso[i] <- idade[i]
            cid := cid + 1
            sid := sid + idade[i]
            mid <- sid / cid
        fimse
   fimpara

   limpatela

    // Impressão das idades por faixas etárias <-ESSA PARTE AQUI TIVE AJUDA
    escreval("Idades por faixa etária")
    escreva ("Menores: ")
    para i de 1 ate ci faca
        escreva (menor[i], ",")
    fimPara
    escreval("")
    escreva ("Adultos: ")
    para i de 1 ate ci faca
        escreva (adulto[i], ",")
    fimPara
    escreval("")
    escreva ("Idosos : ")
    para i de 1 ate ci faca
        escreva (idoso[i], ",")
    fimPara
    escreval("")
    escreval("")
    escreval("-------------------------------------------------------------------")

    // Impressão de quantidades de pessoas por faixa etária e geral
    escreval("Quantidade de pessoas da faixa etária dos Menores: ", cm)
    escreval("Quantidade de pessoas da faixa etária dos Adultos: ", ca)
    escreval("Quantidade de pessoas da faixa etária dos Idosos : ", cid)

    escreval("-------------------------------------------------------------------")

    // Média das idades por faixas etárias e geral
    escreval("Média da faixa etária dos Menores: ", mm)
    escreval("Média da faixa etária dos Adultos: ", ma)
    escreval("Média da faixa etária dos Idosos : ", mid)

    escreval("-------------------------------------------------------------------")

    // Média geral de todas as idades
    escreva("Média geral de todas idades: ", mi)
fimalgoritmo
```

Me ajudem com os erros e com as vírgulas, também preciso que saia as virgulas, alguem sabe como resolver?

Comment: Por favor formate o código corretamente

Comment: Seus cálculos de médias devem ser feitos somente após o término do loop. Seus loops de impressão por faixa etária não devem ir até ci mas sim até cm, ca e cid (as quantidades de pessoas por faixa).